GeeekPi 4 Channel Relay
I am doing a temperature control project and am utilizing the GEEEK Pi 4 Channel Relay hat for Raspberry Pi.
I do not know if this is the right question to ask but what GPIO pins would correlate to each channel for this specific relay.
I am fairly new to electronics so please bear with me.

look up the meaning of the word bare

@jsotola:  good point... that is definitely off topic

You ask about I2C GPIO pins and device channel numbers; its not 1-to-1.  I2C is a two-wire bus interface.  An I2C bus connects multiple devices and is used to pass messages between two devices on the bus.  So the same two GPIO pins are used to pass messages to the relay to control all of the relay channels.  Basically, there are two protocol layers.  An I2C hardware layer allows communication.  A device-specific protocol defines the messages and what they mean. I2C devices often have Linux device drivers that provide an API for controlling that device.  This driver calls the I2C bus driver.

Hopefully this is the same HAT, or at least (functionally) the same as the GeeekPi 4 channel relay hat - it looks the same...

... and the link below also references the GeeekPi Github repository.
From EP-0099

Register Map



Register Address
Function
Value




0x01
Relay 1
0(FULL OFF) - 1/255(ON)


0x02
Relay 2
0(FULL OFF) - 1/255(ON)


0x03
Relay 3
0(FULL OFF) - 1/255(ON)


0x04
Relay 4
0(FULL OFF) - 1/255(ON)




Note that this is relative to the base address, which is set by jumpers:

Base address



DIP switch status icon
Device Address





0x10



0x11



0x12



0x13




The hat uses I2C, and so, from I2C - Inter Integrated Circuit, it uses pins 3 (GPIO2) and 5 (GPIO3) of the GPIO:

In addition, there is a repo with some demo code: dockerpi. In the 4channelRelay directory, the product link, on wiki.52pi.com, is broken. However, after some precise googling, the linked to product page would appear to be the EP-0099 link posted above.
